# How to display result headers in a get request in angular 6

Tags: angular, get

I am unable to display the headers in a result of get request.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApisService {
  link = 'http://13.233.34.68:3000/api/';
  xToken = 'nil';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getToken() {
    if (this.xToken === 'nil') {
      const header1 = new HttpHeaders({'username': 'angular', 'password': '123456'});
      this.http.get(this.link + 'get-token', {headers: header1})
        .subscribe(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result['headers']);
          }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

The result i get in console says 'undefined'.
Please help.

edit:
When using

```
    this.http.get(this.link + 'get-token', {observe: 'response', headers: header1})
    .subscribe(
  (result) => {
    console.log('header keys:', result.headers.keys());
    console.log('header X-ABC:', result.headers.get('X-ABC'));
    console.log(result.body);
}
```

I get the output in console

```
header keys: 
Array(4) [ "cache-control", "content-type", "expires", "pragma" ]
apis.service.ts:18:12
header X-ABC: null apis.service.ts:19:12
Object { success: true }
```

Comment: result is an object.    Object { success: true }     But it is the header files I need.

Answer (score 1):

In options, add `observe: 'response'`, then your return type will be  `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>`. Recent angular, returns `Observable<T>` by default (which is `observe?: 'body'`).

Having `HttpResponse<T>` you may then access the response object.

```
this.http.get(this.link + 'get-token', {observe: 'response', headers: header1})
    .subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log('header keys:', result.headers.keys());
        console.log('header X-ABC:', result.headers.get('X-ABC'));
        console.log(result.body);
      }
    );
```

Angular automatically will attempt to detect the type of body. Which is also controllable with `responseType` option.

Alternative to `response` and `body` is `observe: 'events'`, which will return you `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`. Then you will get events from `HttpClient` as they are available. Events are:

```
type HttpEvent<T> = HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<T> | HttpProgressEvent | HttpUserEvent<T>
```

Reference [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: The headers i get using this method are not the once I am supposed to get. Here I get lazyInit , normalizednames . But I am expecting a x-api-token in the response headers.

Comment: As explained, in order to get access to headers, you have to receive `HttpResponse<T>` from `HttpClient`. For that, you have to explicitly specify it in request options with `observe: 'response'`. Otherwise, you will get content of response only as determined by Angular, be it `json`, `text` etc.

Comment: Yes, I added the observe:   'response' to get header files. But these are not the header files I am expecting

Comment: Inspect you network requests with Chrome Dev Tools for instance, and check if headers received in HTTP response are the same as printed with `console.log(response.headers)` in example above. If you don't see your expected headers in both, then may be you have issue with request and/or backend.

Comment: When i send the same request using Postman , I get all the expected headers. The network requests in browser also shows all the headers that i need. But I am not getting those headers in angular. Please HELP :(

Comment: For me works just fine: `headers 
Array(6) [ "access-control-allow-origin", "connection", "content-length", "date", "x-hello", "x-powered-by" ]`, `header x-hello WORLD`, `header X-Hello WORLD`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185337/discussion-between-dipesh-sinha-and-muradm).

Comment: to receive custom headers, it needs to be done by Server Side. that custom header property need to expose explicitly from Server Side then only you can get